# How to test my const_reverse iterator to match argument list?

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

I am building my very own generic linked list and I'm trying to get test my const reverse iterator. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
sorted_list<int> constIteratorList;
int we = 7;
int io = 1;
int pl = 12;
int jk = 4;
int zx = 13;
constIteratorList.add(we);
constIteratorList.add(io);
constIteratorList.add(pl);
constIteratorList.add(jk);
constIteratorList.add(zx);
const sorted_list<int>& reference = constIteratorList
sorted_list<int>::const_reverse_iterator constIt = reference.rbegin();
```

But the compiler highlights constIteratorList with the red squiggly lines
and says there is no suitable user-defined conversion from
`SortedListReverseIterator<int>` to `SortedListReverseIterator<const int>`. I have a class called SortedListReverseIterator and a SortedListReverseIterator that implements my iterator and reverse iterators. I typedef'd four types of iterators in my sorted_list class--const_reverse_iterator, reverse_iterator, iterator, and const_iterator.

EDIT:
I now tried calling rbegin() on a const reference of constIteratorList, but now in my sorted list call, it says I cannot convert from `Node<T> * const` to `SortedListReverseIterator<T>`.

This is my implementation of rbegin():

```
template <typename T>  
SortedListReverseIterator<const T> sorted_list<T>::rbegin() const  
{  
    return SortedListReverseIterator<const T>(tail);
}
```

I think what the error message is trying to say is that SortedListReverseIterator's constructor doesn't take in a const T, so I tried making another copy constructor for a const T, but that didn't work out..

Answer (score 0):

constIteratorList isn't declared const, so the const version of rbegin wouldn't be getting used (assuming it's been defined).  A possible fix is to create a const reference to the list and then make the call to rbegin on that.